# Is it known why Combo went to jail the first time?

Tags: this-is-england

In the movie *This Is England*, during the scene where Combo comes back in town (with Banjo) Woody introduces him to the group saying :

> This dude here, he spent three years in the pen for me, he never said nothing. If it weren't for him, I wouldn't be with you guys now.

Is it known what this is all about ? I saw the TV shows and the movie multiple times, could never quite grab anything behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was never stated in the film or the series.

The main point is that he took the blame instead of Woody (complicating their relationship), plus that prison radicalized him. The character [was based on real events](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2007/apr/01/2):

> 'I got into the skinheads through my sister going out with one,' Meadows tells me. 'He got me into reggae, and took me out hunting in big gangs. Then a split happened. Whereas with the first skinhead it was all parties and fun, **this other guy was the one who had been to prison and came in with a much darker, political idea**.'